# Created new module, now all products get 404 not found

Tags: magento2, product, frontend-error, web

After following this as a guide: [Github module for grouped product attributes](https://github.com/magento-user/magento2-groupedproducts-attribute)

Now all my product pages give a 404 error.
I am attempting to add all of the attributes to the grouped product collection so that I can access custom attributes from the grouped product page.

I'm not sure how to evaluate where the problem is and/or how to reverse course.
Is there a log file to see what the error might be?
Or can someone take a look at the github link and let me know if that should work?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try bin/magento indexer:reindex and make sure you have elasticsearch running